# Are the controls needed to create Team Explorer extensions available via NuGet?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

As of the VS 2015 SDK, they seem to have switched to NuGet as the source of the SDK reference assemblies, in order to make extension solutions more portable (i.e. developers don't need the whole SDK installed to work on extensions). However, I'm attempting to build a Team Explorer extension, which, according to the [only tutorial I could find on the subject](https://binary-stuff.com/post/getting-start-with-a-team-explorer-plugin-for-vs-2013), requires objects from the [`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.controls(v=vs.120).aspx) assembly. Is there some version of this available from NuGet, so I can continue to avoid referencing the Reference Assemblies directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is one. You need to run the command: **Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ReferenceAssemblies** . Check [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ReferenceAssemblies).

You can also install it via Package Manager, see:
[image]

However, as you checked, there is only 12.0 version, no 14.0 version available.